# Google Directory API - OS version policy compliance

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

On the Google admin console, when looking at chrome devices, you can see their "OS version policy compliance", as seen in the image below:

[image: OS version policy compliance from Google admin console]

However, when retrieving a device from the directory API (using https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices/get), this field does not seem to be returned. My assumption was that the directory API was able to return anything you could see in the admin console. Do I need to use a different API to retrieve this information?

**Update**

I have added [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/223809536) feature request to get this added to the API, as it looks like it is not currently supported.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, Google Workspace Admin SDK does not support retrieval of **OS version policy compliance**. An alternative solution is to use the value of `osVersion` in the response body of [Method: chromeosdevices.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/chromeosdevices/get) and compare it with the OS version specified by your organization's policy.

Note: You can only use the alternative solution to check whether the device is **Compliant** or **Not compliant** since you are only comparing OS versions.

Comment: Thanks Nikko. I will investigate the work around but it is not ideal as in my implementation I will not know the organisation's policy so would have to retrieve this as well. I have raised this feature request to get this added: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/223809536

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to pull the minimum OS version so I can do what you have suggested, but I cannot find an API to do this. Could you point me in the right direction for this?